# QueryDatabaseTableRecord in error with Maximum-value Columns set on column timestamp (oracle)

Tags: oracle, timestamp, apache-nifi

In my nifi network i have to read from an oracle database, listening changes on a timestamp column (setting the Maximum-value Columns with my timestamp column).
But this one produce an exception :

> ```
> data.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month.
> ```

Query in log:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM nfb_core_obj.cache_memory_store
 WHERE date_ins_upd > '01-01-2023 01:01:01'
```

If i try that one in cloudbeaver i got the same error.

If i try to change it in:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM nfb_core_obj.cache_memory_store
 WHERE date_ins_upd > to_timestamp('01-01-2023 01:01:01', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

that works, but is not what i need.
I hope to solve it in nifi processor.

Comment: You just can try to call as `... WHERE date_ins_upd > timestamp'2023-01-01 01:01:01'`, which conforms to timestamp literal, from **the processor** . In the current case( *excerpted from the log* ), 
there's only a literal with no standard.

Comment: I would like to, but in the standard processor nifi , the Maximum-value Column do not admit that kind of...cast, i can only set the name of the column i want in the range check/trigger